# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 on flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code

If I try to run the example app I've got the following exception:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.gradle.internal.compiler.java.ClassNameCollector (in unnamed module @0x3f6a5431) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$TypeSymbol (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.code to unnamed module @0x3f6a5431

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Has somebody an idea how to fix that?
I tried allready

```
flutter clean
flutter create .
flutter pub get
```

and

```
flutter clean
flutter upgrade
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade
```

Repo on github: https://github.com/capoaira/flutter-test

Comment: Could you please tell more about the packages you are using as it may arrises when you use some broken packages or it is happening for counter application in your system.

Comment: I doesn't use packages. All packages in the project are automatily adding.

Comment: Please try this [workaround](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15538#issuecomment-744299876) and see if the error goes away.

Comment: Where I have to insert this code? (Sorry, I am new to the subject)

Comment: Can you share your project in github?

Comment: @MollyWang https://github.com/capoaira/flutter-test

Comment: The code seems to be added to `build.gradle`. I'm not familiar with Flutter, you may ask in github for more help.

Comment: Ok, thanks for you help :)